# Base Color Bake is different to Original Color

Tags: shaders

I am just simply baking the base color of my mesh into an image. However, the baked image is noticably lighter by around 10%. Why is this the case?

[image]
[image]
[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NjFFKZwf1t7YsksplvxGmU-MrC_suzg1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hello could you please share the object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: download has been added

Comment: Yes weird, I can put my finger on why it doesn't bake the good color (switching the Color Management from Filmic to Standard doesn't fix the problem)

Comment: Seems like you have a touch of "Sheen" value in your Principled BSDF. Try to switch it off.

Comment: @SergeL this solved problem for me :D

Comment: wow it was only 0.01  ^^  I think you can write it as the answer  @Serge L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Principled BSDF* has a lot of additional inputs which can alter final look, in this case it was 0.01 value of *Sheen*.

For baking diffuse color pass it's easier to use simple *Diffuse BSDF*, thus keeping initial color and making original shader's settings untouched.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly easier way is to connect the color socket you want to bake directly to the Material Output, and bake the **Emit** type. You also don't have to worry about unchecking Direct/Indirect.

This works because when you connect a color socket (yellow) to a shader socket (green), it's as if there's a default Emission shader node in between.

[image]

The same method will work for a "dumb bake" of any color socket of course, not just Base Color. (If you want to dumb-bake a scalar instead, try putting it in a Principled's Roughness socket and baking the Roughness type.)

Comment: Interesting... What is "dumb bake" please? If it is not just the Base Color, what else color is included in the baked image please?

Comment: By "dumb bake" I mean just the plain value coming out of the socket gets put in the texture, nothing "smart" like shadows, lighting, etc.

Comment: Oh, you mean the raw or original color, which is un-processed or un-edited by any middlemen. Thanks!